# rack run command for automatic file output

Tags: file-io, command-line, cmd, output, racket

From a command prompt (on windows), I try

```
racket text_prog.rkt > output.txt
```

`racket text_prog.rkt` does work but it doesn't work outputting to `output.txt`. The file remains empty.
Are there any other ways I can do this?

Is there a Linux alternative?

Comment: Racket is available on Linux here: http://racket-lang.org/download/

Comment: yeah... i guess &> will work on linux, maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On *nix systems, Racket can be used for shell scripts:

> For example, if racket is installed in "/usr/local/bin", then a file
>   containing the following text acts as a “hello world” script:

```
#! /usr/local/bin/racket

#lang racket/base

"Hello, world!"
```

see: 
http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/scripts.html

Comment: I like where this is going, I finally installed ubuntu today. I'm still trying to figure out how to get output to a file. I had appended &> to catch stder and stdout, unfortunately, &> doesn't seem to be working with php's exec() or system() functions. This could be a security feature, though. If you're not sure what I mean I'll have to repost a similar question with a PHP tag. I suppose your answer could work if there was a directive I could place that the top of a shell script to tell it to output everything to a file?